# HTML5 Image Caption: Image moves to next row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an image gallery. To display captions beneath my images I am using the following code

```
<div>

 <figure>
<img src="sample-image.png" />
<figcaption>Caption Here</figcaption>
</figure>

 </div>
```

Now the problem is when I run the gallery page the images looks like following(figure-1). The second image goes down. I want to display the images like in figure-2, but I don't know what CSS code to write for this or how to fix it. Would you please kindly help me?

Thanks in Advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically just set `display: inline-block; white-space: normal;` for figure and `white-space: nowrap;` to theirs parent (assuming your figures are wrapped in a common container)

Then you will need to make some small adjustments using other properties, (like `vertical-align`)

see this example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CDkNV/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please kindly check this link. I have pasted my code here.  http://jsfiddle.net/SxWbD/4/   Thanks :)

Comment: Your jsfiddle HTML is wrong, it should be one figure per `<figure>` tag, `<figcaption>` being the last child. With that, and `figure {
display: inline-block; }` in place, things look fine for me. Check http://jsfiddle.net/9UQJY/1/

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle that I think goes with Fabrizio's comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nJhwa/1/.  One item of note, if you don't set a width on your `figure` container, a long caption will expand the container and if long enough, make the `figure` container wrap to the next line.  Setting a specific width (same as the `img`) will wrap the caption text.  Applying `vertical-align:top` to `figure` should make them look good.